# Correct way to update Start, end and duration of sibling events in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, design-patterns

I got a activity/event component that has input fields for start, stop and duration.. when either of them are changed the others are updated.. I will have multiple activity/events and if eg the end time of the previous event is changed so that it ends after the next one it needs to update the start time of the next.. how should I do this? I am thinking a linked list here with previous and next "pointers", but not sure what is the correct way to do this in react? Is there a react design pattern I can look into for this?

I'm new with react and quiet new with web dev. Any good sources for common design patterns?

Comment: not react related ... use an ordered [by time] array ... on insert search for placing in the chain (between slices) ... on updates [on insert too] modify neighbours   ... but it's a kind of hardcoding, there should be a conflict state to be resolved by user (decision - which entry needs to be modified)

Comment: but how do I get the start and end times states out of the other components?

Comment: no need ... it's data driven ... read some react todo tutorial